# Етимологія слова «нісно»

Tags: етимологія, діалектизми, архаїзми

**Нісно** — постійно:

- найчастіше в нейтральному сенсі про щось, що відбувається постійно, безупинно, раз-у-раз. Але, з ефектом підсилення тривалості у часі: *«вони нісно говорили»* те саме, що й *«вони без кінця говорили»* або *«вони говорили та й говорили»*.
- може мати негативну конотацію, якщо одноманітні дії викликають роздратування у <strike>оточуючих</strike> присутніх, тобто про щось набридливе, надокучливе. (Часто при такому його вживанні щодо людини [винуватця] вираз також передає прихований наказ «Досить! Припини!»).

Цікаво, хтось з присутніх, крім мене (Поділля), чув або вживав це слово. На жаль,  не можу знайти хоч щось про нього. Це свідчить, що слово є малопоширеним діалектизмом або архаїзмом? Із походження припускаю, що воно пов'язано із польським *nieznośny (набридливий, занудливий)*?  Можливо це слово зустрічається в іншому вигляді?

Приклади вжитку:

- *«Ти з другом був, ви говорили нісно».* <sup>(із "ВКонтакті", "Сплетни Хмельницький")</sup>
- *«Чого ти нісно нипаєш!»* <sup>(Моє)</sup>
- *«Нісно сидиш і сидиш там певно дира вже».* <sup>(із Ask.fm)</sup>
- *«Падаєш нісно».* <sup>(звідти ж)</sup>

Comment: Є варіант «ніцно»: [1](//reibert.info/threads/doslidzhennja-dialektiv-doluchajtesja.430827/), [2](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=ніцно), [3](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/talking-head), [4](http://www.poetryclub.com.ua/getpoem.php?id=679143), [5](//dialectstat.wikispaces.com/file/view/new_dialect202.png). Вжитків, здається, значно більше — припускаю, що це основний варіант.

Comment: Чисто припущення — від слова «ніц» («нічого», іноді «ніяк», «ніколи»)? Хоча значення, фактично, протилежне — але (1) так іноді трапляється; (2) в українській мові практикують підсилення заперечення, тому, наприклад, «ніц у мене не виходить» ≈ «постійно в мене не виходить». Але це суто необґрунтоване припущення.

Comment: Центральна Україна, ніколи не чув.

Comment: Іще часто пишуть «ніц но» ([1](http://risovach.ru/kartinka/9062237), [2](http://risovach.ru/kartinka/10885747), [3](http://risovach.ru/kartinka/9125041), [4](//www.facebook.com/upa.volya/posts/611782262231714), [5](http://www.svoboda-news.com/lys/pdf_arxiv/1976-1.pdf)) і навіть «ніц-но» ([1](//doba.te.ua/post/31740)).

Comment: Тому ще одна теорія: від (спочатку) неправильної інтерпретації стику «[ніц](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/33146-nic.html#show_point)» («нічого») і «[но](http://sum.in.ua/s/no)» (значення 3 — «тільки»). Наприклад, «не робить нічого, тільки в своєму комп'ютері сидить» → «не робить ніц, но в своєму комп'ютері сидить» → «не робить, ніцно в своєму комп'ютері сидить». Приклади такіх випадкових стиків: «Кіт і граф Попеловський» ([1](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/Кіт_і_граф_Попеловський), [2](http://www.ebk.net.ua/Book/buunt/kpt/part3/325.htm)).

Comment: P.S.: Київ, ніколи не чув (але я й «ніц» до певного віку ніколи не чув).

Comment: @Sasha о, дякую за наведення. Хоча мене дещо бентежить  означення "завжди", "постійно" більш відповідне. Але це, можливо, місцеві відмінності. Про зв'язок з "ніц" у мене теж була така думка, та, напевно, такий зв'язок малоймовірний.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Синоніми

Як правильно зазначає у коментарях @Sasha, це слово виглядає як ланцюжок у омонімічній лінійці *ні**т**но, ні**ц**но, ні**с**но*.

#### Вживання

Слово *«ніцно = завжди»* присутнє на [мапі діалектів](https://dialectstat.wikispaces.com/main_rez) (№ 202) проекту [DialectStat](https://dialectstat.wikispaces.com/).
<sub>(**Оновлено** листопад/2018: гостинг Wikispaces закрито, будь ласка, допоможіть оновити посилання)</sub>

І воно, дійсно, виглядає як типове для Поділля:

[image: Слово ніцно на мапі діалектів]
<sub>*Image courtesy of [DialectStat](https://dialectstat.wikispaces.com/)*.</sub>

*Легенда (значення кольорів на мапі)*:

1. ніколи не чув цього слова;
2. знаю, але ніколи не вживаю;
3. вкрай рідко вживаю;
4. вживаю час від часу, або на рівні з іншим аналогом;
5. активно вживаю тільки такий варіант слова.

#### Етимологія

[Етимологічний словник української мови](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) містить статтю про слово [`ніт`](http://sum.in.ua/s/nit), яке, як вважається, є результатом злиття виразу «* *не є ту*» (< [ПСЛ](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) `ne je(stь) tu`)

Логічно припустити, що *ніцно* утворилося за допомогою цілком стандартного прислiвникового суфікса `-но`, у значенні «нічого іншого окрім…».

Тобто, *«ніцно говорити»* = *«не робити нічого іншого, окрім як говорити»*.

Можна порівняти зі словом *лише (лишень)* у значенні «виключно, тільки», яке має подібну логіку утворення від *лишати, позбавляти* (усього іншого).

Answer (score 7):

Думаю, що це артефакт, який залишився від старих діалектів.
Наприклад, дослівний переклад з польської:

`Nie robię nic - Не роблю нічого (Не роблю ніц)`

Слово ніцно я б розділяв на два слова - ніц но (нічого, крім).

Моя прабаба (мешканка Яворівщини) вживала це слово в значення наведеному bytebuster - «не робити нічого іншого, окрім як», а також «постійно», «весь час», а не «завжди», як це наведено на карті діалектів. Наприклад

`Ніц но ходить по дворі - Весь час ходить по дворі`

`Ніц но прийде, почне розказувати... - Постійно коли приходить, почне розказувати...`

В останньому реченні «постійно» можна синонімічно замінити на «завжди», але НМД слово «завжди» не зажди можна замінити на «постійно» (ніцно).

Comment: Про поділ на два слова – дуже слушна думка.